# How does Test and Set operation satisfy mutual exclusion when we have only load and store instructions as atomic operations?

Tags: operating-system

Atomic operation of Test and Set instruction are

1.LOAD LOCK, REGISTER
2.STORE #1,LOCK

so now if a process P1 comes and it sets the value of lock variable as 1 and gets preempted , now when other processes will come they will also set the value of lock variable 1 so now how is it guranteed which process will enter the critical section.

since other instructions after it are

3.CMP REGISTER,#0
4.JNZ step1

so now when P1 comes the output of comparator would be false so that means P1 will also be in busy waiting , I am a bit confused in this ,please clarify it .
I have already gone through other posts related to it but I am not getting it .

Answer (score 0):

The process that changed the value from 0 to 1 sees 0 as the "old value" and will proceed.

When another process comes along, they will get 1 as the "old value" and will loop until it becomes 0.